# Some blissfully ignorant math?

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, optimization, formation-of-numbers

I was playing around with the code for my game the other day in an effort to create some *unique* effects. One thing I created was what I called an "ignorant assignment" in which I applied arithmetic with complete disregard for the traditional order of operations so that the order of operations is sequential (e.g. applied in the visually presented order). Here are two *simple* examples and their expected outcomes:

$$1 + 3 \cdot 5 \div 2 + 1 = 11$$
$$-1 + 3 \cdot 5 \div 2 + 1 = 6$$

Using only the numbers $1$ through $9$ (to include their negative counterparts) and the foundational operations of addition ($+$), subtraction ($-$), multiplication ($\cdot$), and division ($\div$), what is the optimal <sub>[1]</sub> "ignorant assignment" so that each step of the evaluation process will output each of the numbers $0$ through $15$ **no more than** once? <sub>[2]</sub>

---

There *are*, of course, some rules that must be followed:

- Two of the same digit may not follow each other (e.g. $1 + 1$ is **not** allowed).
- Concatenation is **not** allowed (e.g. you **cannot** combine $1$ and $2$ to create $12$).
- The numbers $1$ through $9$ may be used **no more than** thrice each.

<sub>***1**: For the purposes of this puzzle, optimal means using the least instances of the same digit (e.g. use each digit as few times as possible); along with having the **lowest** sum.*</sub>
<sub>***2**: The order of the output doesn't matter.*</sub>

Comment: Hoping this isn't *too* easy, it took me a while to find what I considered a *decent* balance.

Comment: Does inputting a 5 as the first digit count as 5 being output?

Comment: @Bass that's a fair question, but no. A *step* in the context of this puzzle is defined as performing a mathematical operation (e.g. $5 + 1 - 3 = 3$ in two steps of $5 + 1 = 6 - 3 = 3$). As such, the first step outputs $6$ and the second outputs $3$.

Answer (score 6):

According to the two constraints we're given (fewest repetitions of any digit and lowest sum), a theoretical ideal solution should

> use the digits from 1 to 8 twice each and 9 once, a total of 17 numbers, as there are 16 steps.

Here's a solution that achieves this:

> `8 + 3 - 5 + 7 + 1 / 7 * 6 / 4 + 6 - 2 + 8 - 5 - 9 - 1 + 4 * 2 - 3`
>     `11   6  13  14   2  12   3   9   7  15  10   1   0   4   8   5`